# getting this on dataframe 'int' object has no attribute 'lower'

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

```
df23 = pd.DataFrame({'name':['MY NAME1', 'MY NAME2', 'MY NAME3','MY NAME4'],
                    'description': [['d1 d2 d3'], ['d4 d5 d6'], ['d7 d8 d9'],['a9 d0 t5']],
                   'specialties': ['green,red,blue', 'green,purple,pink', 'yellow,white,black,red,green', 'bub.tub,rub'],
                    })
df_work['name'] = [x for x in df_work['name'].map(lambda x: x.lower())]
```

I want to convert all entries in name col to lower. But i am getting this error.

Comment: what is `df_work` ? Is this `df23`? If so it works well to me

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If df_work is an existing dataframe then you may use:

```
df_work['name'] = df23['name'].apply(lambda x: x.lower())
```

else use:

```
df_work = pd.DataFrame(df23['name'].apply(lambda x: x.lower()), columns = ['name'])
```

Answer (score 6):

It seems some value is integer, so is necessary converting to `string`:

```
df_work['name'] = [x for x in df_work['name'].map(lambda x: str(x).lower())]
```

Another solution with [`Series.astype`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.astype.html) and [`Series.str.lower`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.lower.html):

```
df_work['name'] = df_work['name'].astype(str).str.lower()
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

`df23['name'] = df23['name'].astype('str').map(lambda x: x.lower())`